# Why is alias not working with groupby and count

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running the following block and I'm wondering why `.alias` is not working:

```
data = [(1, "siva", 100), (2, "siva", 200),(3, "siva", 300),
        (4, "siva4", 400),(5, "siva5", 500)]
schema = ['id', 'name', 'sallary']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
display(df.select('name').groupby('name').count().alias('test'))
```

Is there a specific reason? In which case `.alias()` is supposed to be working in a similar situation? Also why no errors are being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change syntax a bit to apply alias with no issue:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select('name').groupby('name').agg(F.count("name").alias("test")).show()

# output
+-----+----+
| name|test|
+-----+----+
|siva4|   1|
|siva5|   1|
| siva|   3|
+-----+----+
```

I am not 100% sure, but my understanding is that when you use `.count()` it returns entire Dataframe so in fact `.alias()` is applied to entire Dataset instead of single column that's why it does not work.